# How can i extract coordinates from a kml file using Java

Tags: java, automation, maps, kml, google-earth

I have a KML file https://files.fm/u/nbwf3trv and i need to fetch all coordinates and add it to a list.

Example: Required coordinates from KML file.
11.651548147201538,48.249088525772095,0 9.20654296875,50.00086069107056,0 7.010795159396929,51.45182674763414,0".

Please suggest.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

JAK (Java API for KML) is a simple Java API to parse and/or create KML files from scratch.

https://github.com/micromata/javaapiforkml

Here is a snippet of Java code to extract the coordinates from a KML file. In this case it's a placemark and a polygon geometry. If the KML file had multiple placemarks then you would iterate over all the placemarks.

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Kml.class);

// create KML reader to parse arbitrary KML into Java Object structure
Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
Kml kml = (Kml) u.unmarshal(new File("test.kml"));

Placemark placemark = (Placemark) kml.getFeature();
Polygon geom = (Polygon) placemark.getGeometry();
LinearRing linearRing = geom.getOuterBoundaryIs().getLinearRing();
List<Coordinate> coordinates = linearRing.getCoordinates();
for (Coordinate coordinate : coordinates) {
    System.out.println(coordinate.getLongitude());
    System.out.println(coordinate.getLatitude());
    System.out.println(coordinate.getAltitude());
}
```

If the first feature in the KML is a Folder then you can cast a Folder to the object then iterate over the features.

```
Folder doc = (Folder) kml.getFeature();
List<Feature> features = doc.getFeature();
for(Feature f : features) {
  ...
}
```

You can also use the [Java Topology Suite](https://github.com/locationtech/jts) (JTS). An example reading a kml file is posted [here](https://github.com/locationtech/jts/blob/master/modules/example/src/main/java/org/locationtech/jtsexample/io/gml2/KMLReaderExample.java). JTS is an active open source project.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried the code. But it says "java.lang.ClassCastException: de.micromata.opengis.kml.v_2_2_0.Folder cannot be cast to de.micromata.opengis.kml.v_2_2_0.Placemark".

Comment: And also i want the coordinates from  <Placemark id="1.5.2"> . Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the first element in KML is a Folder (see update in answer with Folder) then change the casting to a Folder element and iterate over its children. Likewise your placemarks may have different geometries so will need to test for geometry type if you have mixed types. Best to download the source and generate javadoc from it to view the API calls.